# XML Parser blocking main thread and dispatch_async crashing app

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, uitableview, dispatch-async

i am developing an application and in this app i am loading xml data in a uitableview and that table view call parse method after every 5 secs and reload uitable to load new data. Everything was working fine but app got stuck when parsing starts after 5 sec so i decided to implement dispatch_async in parse method but after that application is crashing like after 5 sec whenever app reload uitable. here is my code.

```
- (void) Parse{
    previusCount = rssOutputData.count;
    rssOutputData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
     NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"https://messages_%@.xml",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"xmls_id"]];
     NSData *xmlData=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post]];
     xmlParserObject =[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:xmlData];
     [xmlParserObject setDelegate:self];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [xmlParserObject parse];
         [messageList reloadData];
         if (previusCount != rssOutputData.count) {
             NSInteger bottomRow = [rssOutputData count] - 1; // this is your count's array.
             if (bottomRow >= 0) {
      ///////getting to latest msg/////////////
                 NSIndexPath *indexPathnew = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:bottomRow inSection:0];
                 [self.messageList scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPathnew atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
             }
         }
     });
    });
}
```

Method through which i am sending a message to the xml data file.

```
- (IBAction)sendClicked:(id)sender {
    [messageText resignFirstResponder];
    if ( [messageText.text length] > 0 ) {
        NSString *rawStr;
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"userType"] == 1) { 
        rawStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data=%@&user_id=%@&session_id=%@", messageText.text, [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"therapist_id"],[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"xmls_id"]];
    } else{//////In case of Patient
        rawStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data=%@&user_id=%@&session_id=%@", messageText.text, [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"patient_id"],[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"xmls_id"]];
    }
        NSData *data = [rawStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://do_add_message.php"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setHTTPBody:data];
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *err;
        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
        NSLog(@"responseData: %@", responseData);
        //////////////////////
        [self Parse];
    }

    messageText.text = @"";
}
```

And the Error which i am getting is:
[image: Error]

Comment: check your array, might be your array is getting nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print your array. Check it twice. I think you are getting an empty array. Print every object in the console which you get from server and which you parse. So you will get idea.

**Update:**

Just reload the table data on the main thread and don't parse data on it. like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [messageList reloadData];
});
```

Put the other code outside the main thread.

Comment: if i comment// these lines everything works fine             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     });
    });

Comment: Then why you using main thread to parse data ? just reload tableview on main thread. nothing more

Comment: @Lion can you please explain how am i going to do that with the example of my code! how can i use it in parse? i dont want my uitable to stuck every time

Comment: Thanks i tried this one but after doing this uitable again stuck after 5 sec when reloading it so problem remains the same but now its not crashing. Thanks :)

Comment: and now this is new error i am getting now [UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]: row (10) beyond bounds (10) for section (0).'

Comment: first get all data and reload table at last. so your last task should be reload table

Comment: no now its giving me that error instead of first one. not reloading table.

Comment: keep this line on main thread also. you should put UI related changes in main thread